# Read pandas data and convert it to IMMA

Tags: python, pandas, data

I'm working on a project in which my data set is in xarray and I need to write it to IMMA format. I converted it from xarray to pandas and am totally stumped on how to go from pandas to IMMA. Any advice? Would it be easier to go straight from xarray to IMMA? I am working in python by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following module provides a Python API to [IMMA files](https://icoads.noaa.gov/e-doc/imma/):

```py
import IMMA
```

You could use [write()](http://brohan.org/pyIMMA/module_IMMA.html#IMMA.write)

```py
opfile=open('some_output_file.imma','w')
for ob in obs:
    IMMA.write(ob,opfile)
```

More info could be found [here](http://brohan.org/pyIMMA/module_IMMA.html#IMMA.write).